# Why am I getting "Can not read property 0 of undefined", when the object is very much there and I am trying to access it within scope?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, scope, javascript-objects

I have a function like

```
(function next(index) {

  var someObject = { 0:{some:"one"}, 1:{thing:"none"}, 2:{seconds: 5} };

  setTimeout(function() {
    //code ...
  }, (someObject[0][seconds]*1000) );

)(0);
```

And I am getting the following error in the *second last line*

**`myscript.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`**

It seems to be a scope problem, because I tried to access the 0th key like someObject[0] as well as someObject.0 but no luck.

But according to my understanding, `someObject` is  defined in the same scope as the call to `setTimeout()`. So why am I getting this error. How co I fix this?

Comment: What is `seconds`?

Comment: `someObject[0]` is the object `{some: "one"}`; what is `seconds`?

Comment: The code shown won't ever throw the given error. Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access `[seconds]` using bracket notation, it attempts to evaluate the variable `seconds` and uses that result to determine the property to access. Specify it in string format `['seconds']` or use period notation as noted here:

```js
var someObject = { 0:{some:"one"}, 1:{thing:"none"}, 2:{seconds: 5} };


try {
  console.log(someObject[2][seconds]*1000);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
console.log(someObject[2].seconds*1000);
```

Additionally: `someObject[0]` is `{some: "one"}` which doesn't have any `seconds` parameter on it. I suspect you were trying to demonstrate `someObject[2]` instead.